# SimpleDateFormat date and time pattern

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

*9 PM CST 14 NOV 16 or 9:30 PM CST 14 NOV 16*

If my string is the date and time above, what should be my date and time pattern that i could use for SimpleDateFormat? Im not sure what should be the pattern if the time could be 9 only or 9:30.

Is this correct?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m aaa z d MMM yy");
```

I tried testing the above code. For sample date 9:30 PM CST 14 NOV 16, it's working. But for 9 PM CST 14 NOV 16, it's throwing an exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "9 PM CST 14 NOV 16"

Comment: did you try it in a little throwaway script with some sample dates? try it.

Comment: I edited my post. It's throwing an exception for the sample date "9 PM CST 14 NOV 16".

Comment: `9:00` will work, your format requires `m`

Comment: your date format looks wrong. look at this example format, then read associated tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/FormatcurrentdateandtimewiththeSimpleDateFormatHHmmss.htm

Comment: Are you asking if you can parse two date formats with one `SimpleDateFormat`? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @shmosel Hi yes. Is it better if i could first format the date i'm receiving(either 9 PM CST 14 NOV 16 or 9:30 PM CST 14 NOV 16) to my desired format h:m aaa z d MMM yy then that's the time ill parse the date? Or are there other ways.

Comment: Excuse me, @Pseudonymous, are you forgetting to accept answers? Though still asking qualified questions, it seems to me last time you accepted an answer was in October?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method that tries multiple date format patterns:

```
public static Date parseDate(String dateToParse) {
    String[] dateFormats = {"h aaa z d MMM yy", "h:m aaa z d MMM yy"};

    for (String dateFormat : dateFormats) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(dateToParse);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then

```
Date date1 = parseDate("9 PM CST 14 NOV 16");
System.out.println(date1);
Date date2 = parseDate("9:30 PM CST 14 NOV 16");
System.out.println(date2);
```

outputs

```
Mon Nov 14 22:00:00 EST 2016
Mon Nov 14 22:30:00 EST 2016
```